# Variable causing append to not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

In IE9 compatibility view off and in other major browsers (chrome, firefox, safari and opera) it appends a table row underneath when I click on the `Add Question` Button.

But if I turn on compatibility view in IE, it appends a blank into table below.

Now what I have realised is that if I remove this line of code below:

```
var flag = true;
```

Then it works with compatibility view in IE, but I will get an error in error console stating flag is undefined.

So how can I fix it so that I get no error in console but that its able to append table rows into the table in IE compatibility on?

Code is below:

```
var flag = true;

if(flag == true)
{
    var tbl_qanda = $("#qandatbl").width();
    $("#qandatbl").css({"width": (tbl_qanda - 16)+ "px"});
}

var tbl_qanda_onthefly = $("#qandatbl_onthefly").width();

if(tbl_qanda > tbl_qanda_onthefly)
{
     $("#qandatbl").css({"width": (tbl_qanda_onthefly - 16)+ "px"});
     $("#qandatbl_onthefly_container").css({"width": (tbl_qanda_onthefly)+ "px"});
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is jsfiddle to show you code: http://jsfiddle.net/7GjYK/

To see working version, To see what is happening please use this link [DEMO](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text23.php) and open it up in IE9 compatibility off or in any other major browser and you see that when you click `Add Question`, it appends a table row underneath, but if you change the compatibility view on and do same thing, it shows a blank append.

Comment: You never need to compare a boolean value against `true` or `false` in  a conditional statement. `if(flag)` is sufficient.

Comment: I know the question was about IE... but trying it in safari I get it doesn't seem to find the insertQuestion function.

Comment: demo doesn't work in any browser due to not including jQuery and use of out of scope function. At least post a  demo that works!

Comment: My apologies everybody, saved the latest file in wrong place so it contained the file which wasn't working before I put in the working demo. Please use the DEMO now as it is now working so you can follow it

Comment: @MattBall but then I get an error stating flag is undefined, do I just include `var flag;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just keep it IE9 by disabling the compatibility:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`